# WooCommerce orderby template disappears and not longer works on search page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search, order

i have Problem and no solution :/

when i search in a product_cat and the URL looks like

http://example.com/wprest/shop/?product_cat=clothing&s=ninja

the orderby is no longer showing

and: 
?orderby=popularity&product_cat=clothing&s=ninja

has no effect on the search results page

how can i bring back the orderby from woocommerce for Search results page?

thanks